primefaces add message to upload file component not working
I 'm using Primefaces to upload files, I want to check the size of all the files that will be uploaded if the size is over the limit. I've managed to check the size of all files but I cant display any message.
FI: the check of file type is working and the message warning is displayed.
the scroll also is working.
What can I do?
    
 <p:fileUpload id="attachmentUpload"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{documentLibrary.checkFileSize}"
                                      label="#{msg.upload}"
                                      mode="advanced" multiple="true" styleClass="fileupload-buttonbar-white"
                                      auto="true" update="attachmentPanel"
                                      onstart="#{request.requestURI.contains('document/edit') ? 'PF(\'editWidgetVar\').disable(), PF(\'documentWizardWidgetVar\').hideNextNav(), PF(\'documentWizardWidgetVar\').hideBackNav()' : 'PF(\'documentWizardWidgetVar\').hideNextNav(), PF(\'documentWizardWidgetVar\').hideBackNav()'}"
                                      oncomplete="#{request.requestURI.contains('document/edit') ? 'PF(\'editWidgetVar\').enable(), PF(\'outgoingDocumentWizardWidgetVar\').showNextNav(), PF(\'outgoingDocumentWizardWidgetVar\').showBackNav()' : 'PF(\'outgoingDocumentWizardWidgetVar\').showNextNav(), PF(\'outgoingDocumentWizardWidgetVar\').showBackNav()'}"
                                      invalidFileMessage="#{of:format1(val['invalid_file_type'], documentLibrary.allowedExtensions)}"
                                      allowTypes="#{documentLibrary.allowedExtensions}"
                                       />
                        <p:message id="fileWarnMessage" for="attachmentUpload" autoUpdate="true" />


and
public void checkFileSize(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ...
        if(size > sizeLimit){
            //MessageUtils.createBasicMessage("annex_exceed_3Mb", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "form:documentEditComponent:attachmentUpload");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form:documentEditComponent:attachmentUpload", MessageUtils.createMessage("validation.messages", "file_exceed_limit", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN));
            PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:documentEditComponent:attachmentUpload");
            PrimeFaces.current().scrollTo("form:documentEditComponent:attachmentUpload");
        }
}

Primefaces version: 7.0
java version: 8

you didn't mention your version of PrimeFaces? Please edit the ticket with your PF version etc.
